# Https communication between services in docker-compose

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, https, docker-compose, ssl-certificate

I have two services specified in docker-compose - `api` and `web` that depends on api. Both are aspnet core web applications

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  api:
    image: mywebapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyWebApi/Dockerfile
  ports:
    - "44380:443"

  web:
    image: mywebapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyWebApp/Dockerfile
    environment:
     - ApiClient__Uri=https://api
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - api
```

I can use self-signed dev certificates to access any of these services from localhost if I mount certificates from the host

```
    volumes:
     - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https
```

But I want to access `api` from `web` via `https://api/foo` without mapping any `api` ports to the host.

How can I issue a certificate for `api` by some CA trusted by `web`? Or maybe there is another secure way to do https communication between two services?

Comment: Create your own certificate authority (e.g. using `openssl` or `xca` or something). Configure your images to trust the CA certificate. Create a certificate for "api" and inject that into your image.